# Using mouseover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a jquery that by a mouseover change the contain of the first `<ul>`, the first `<ul>` by default contains `111` and when the mouse is over `aaa` appears `111`, `bbb` appears `222`, `ccc` appears `333`

```js
const firstul = document.getElementById('span_Lan');
const boxLi = document.getElementById('ul_box').children;
for (let i = 0; i < boxLi.length; i++) {
  boxLi[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    firstul.value += boxLi[i].textContent;
    if (boxLi[i].id == "lnk1") firstul.value += "111";
    else if (boxLi[i].id == "lnk2") firstul.value += "222";
    else if (boxLi[i].id == "lnk2") firstul.value += "333";
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="li_box"> <span id="span_Lan"></span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul_box">
    <li><a id="lnk1" class="">aaa</a></li>
    <li><a id="lnk2" class="">bbb</a></li>
    <li><a id="lnk3" class="">ccc</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please proof-read your question and fix any issues with the format _before_ you submit it

Comment: _"the first `<ul>` by default contains 111"_ - An `<ul>` only contains `<li>` elements. And only those `<li>` elements can have other elements/texts. But the first `<li>` has no `111` text...

Comment: *I want to write [some] jquery* - none of your code uses [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) - do you want a *jquery* solution?   Or are you just mixing jquery with javascript?  As the provided answer shows you don't *need* jquery, but if your requirement is that it must be in jquery, then please be clear.   If jquery: here's a succinct two-liner without hardcoding "111" etc : https://jsfiddle.net/jczwo34s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code

- you need to use `innerText` or `innerHtml` instead of `value`
- next you need to pass the event into your mouse over and use the current target instead of `boxLi[i]`
- finally, move your ids to the li as that is what the mouse over is on

Also this isn't jQuery

```js
const firstul = document.getElementById('span_Lan');
const boxLi = document.getElementById('ul_box').children;
for (let i = 0; i < boxLi.length; i++) {
  boxLi[i].addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    firstul.innerText = e.currentTarget.textContent;                     // not sure if you want this line - it's in your code but your question  says nothing about having the letters in the first ul
    if (e.currentTarget.id == "lnk1") firstul.innerText += "111";
    else if (e.currentTarget.id == "lnk2") firstul.innerText += "222";
    else if (e.currentTarget.id == "lnk3") firstul.innerText += "333";
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="li_box"> <span id="span_Lan">111</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul_box">
    <li id="lnk1"><a class="">aaa</a></li>
    <li id="lnk2"><a class="">bbb</a></li>
    <li id="lnk3"><a class="">ccc</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You said using jQuery , so no need to loops and addEventListener , all you need is just specifying displayed data inside link using data attribute (like data-text in below snippet )

use the [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) listener then access current hovered by using **`$(this)`** key word , then display the data , that's all

See below snippet :

```js
const $firstul = $('#span_Lan');

$("#ul_box li").hover(function() {
  $firstul.html( $(this).find('a').data("text") )
})
```

```css
#ul_box li {
  border:1px solid black;
}

#ul_box li:hover {
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="li_box"> <span id="span_Lan"></span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul_box">
    <li><a id="lnk1" data-text="111" class="">aaa</a></li>
    <li><a id="lnk2" data-text="222" class="">bbb</a></li>
    <li><a id="lnk3" data-text="333" class="">ccc</a></li>
    <li><a id="lnk3" data-text="444" class="">ddd</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Really smart to use data attributes :)

Comment: @RemcoKersten thanks , that's the usual way to use custom data ;)

Answer (score 1):

To make your code a bit more readable, you should use `querySelectorAll` to select the links. Then run over the elements with `forEach` to add an `eventListener` per element.

In the example below I have created a function called *handleMouseOver*. This function expects an id as a parameter, which is the id of the listitem.

The function then fires a switch statement to determine which text belongs to this ID. This text is then applied to your *span_Lan* element.

I also call the function once when initiating the script, to fill in the default value (namely 111).

```js
const firstul = document.getElementById('span_Lan');

document.querySelectorAll('#ul_box li').forEach(e => e.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => handleMouseOver(e.target.id)));
                                                                        
function handleMouseOver(id) {
  let text;
  switch (id) {
    case "lnk1":
      text = "111"
      break;
      case "lnk2":
      text = "222"
      break;
      case "lnk3":
      text = "333"
      break;
    default:
      text = "111"
  }
  firstul.innerText = text;
}

handleMouseOver();
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="li_box"> <span id="span_Lan"></span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul_box">
    <li><a id="lnk1" class="">aaa</a></li>
    <li><a id="lnk2" class="">bbb</a></li>
    <li><a id="lnk3" class="">ccc</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```